# Unresolved identifier "PFFacebookUtils" in swift in Xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, xcode6

I am trying to have users login to facebook with parse but am receiving the compiler error "Use of unresolved identifier" for PFFacebookUtils, Parse, FBAppCall, and an invalid DidBecomeActive

This question has been posted before and the solution was to add the parsefacebookutils framework into your project and import it into the header file. However, I have already added the framework to my project and imported it into my header file by adding the following to the my header.

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/facebookSDK.h>
```

I am still getting the error. The following is the code from my appdelegate file:

```
import UIKit




@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
        Parse.setApplicationId("parseAppId", clientKey:"parseClientKey")
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication,
            withSession:PFFacebookUtils.session())
}

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())

}
```

Could you please take a look at my code above? Not sure what the solution is.

Comment: think you need to add the framework Social aswell

Comment: From the Facebook website: Please note: if you are using Apple's Social framework, you may continue to do so, but ensure that if the user is not using the iOS integration, that your app falls back to the Facebook SDK for iOS. This can create more work than necessary, though, so we highly recommend using our SDK instead.

Everything I have done so far has been through the facebook and parse websites, it hasn't said anything about the social framework. The errors i'm getting seem like although i've imported the framework, xcode is still not recognizing PFFacebookUtils for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You have to go into the Build Settings - Objective C Header and then type the path to your header in the debug name. For example ProjectName/HeaderName.h as according to where I had my file within my project. Normally you wouldn't have to do this, but it didn't populate for me when I created the header.

Comment: And don't forget to add the FacebookSDK to the project if you haven't already.